# How many containers contain at least one item?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have X containers with Y slots each. The containers are not unique.

I also have n items that are to be placed in any of the X * Y slots at random. n is always less than X * Y.

How would I find the number of containers with at least one item that is statistically most likely? Is this possible to determine theoretically?

Comment: So you can only place one item per slot?  When you go to place an item, do you pick a slot at random from among the empty ones, or pick a container at random and put the item in it?  In the latter case, what if the container is full?

Comment: @RossMillikan You can only place one item per slot. When you place an item, you can pick any empty slot at random. All empty slots across all containers should have equal probability of getting picked. If a container is full, it can hold no more items, since there are no more slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this may be quite difficult in general, though for $Y=1$ the answer is $n$

But a related question is the expected number of containers with *exactly* one item (i.e. the mean rather than the mode): that would be $X\dfrac{{Y \choose 1}{XY-Y \choose n-1}}{XY \choose n} = \dfrac{n(XY-Y)!(XY-n)! }{(XY-Y-n+1)!(XY-1)!}$

You then edited the question to *at least* one item.  Here the expected number is $X\left(1-\dfrac{XY-Y \choose n}{XY \choose n}\right)$

Comment: I swear I mess up every time I post to stack exchange. The question is supposed to be how many containers with _at least_ one item is statistically most likely. I reread the question half a dozen times before I posted and still didn't catch my mistake.

Comment: @EdwardCasey Many *least one* questions are easier to calculate if you approach them as an *exactly zero* question and then adjust the answer, as in my final "$1-$"

Comment: Yes, I did learn that trick back in college, but it's been so long since I did probabilities that I legitimately didn't know how to structure the rest of the expression.